# Query on string not working in SPARQL with Fuseki (MAKG dataset)

Tags: sparql, fuseki, microsoft-academic-graph

I would like to make a SPARQL query using MAKG (Microsoft Academic Knowledge Graph) (https://makg.org/) and DBPedia datasets (using `SERVICE` keyword) on Apache Jena Fuseki.

Before that, I want to test some simpler queries for just MAKG such as:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX magc: <https://makg.org/class/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX fabio: <http://purl.org/spar/fabio/>
PREFIX prism: <http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.0/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT distinct ?paperTitle ?paperPubDate
WHERE {
        ?paper rdf:type magc:Paper .
        ?paper prism:keyword "hydrogen"^^xsd:string .
        ?paper fabio:hasDiscipline ?field .
        ?paper dcterms:title ?paperTitle .
        ?paper prism:publicationDate ?paperPubDate .
}
LIMIT 100
```

It retrieves papers with a keyword equals to `"hydrogen"`.

Using MAKG endpoint https://makg.org/sparql, it's working well ([result](https://makg.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+magc%3A+%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fmakg.org%2Fclass%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dcterms%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+fabio%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fspar%2Ffabio%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+prism%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fprismstandard.org%2Fnamespaces%2Fbasic%2F2.0%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+xsd%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+distinct+%3FpaperTitle+%3FpaperPubDate%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A%3Fpaper+rdf%3Atype+magc%3APaper+.%0D%0A%3Fpaper+prism%3Akeyword+%22hydrogen%22%5E%5Exsd%3Astring+.%0D%0A%3Fpaper+fabio%3AhasDiscipline+%3Ffield+.%0D%0A%3Fpaper+dcterms%3Atitle+%3FpaperTitle+.%0D%0A%3Fpaper+prism%3ApublicationDate+%3FpaperPubDate+.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT+100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+)).
But if I test the same query on Apache Jena Fuseki, it retrieves no row.

```
SELECT ?paperTitle ?paperPubDate WHERE {
  SERVICE <https://makg.org/sparql> {
    ?paper rdf:type magc:Paper .
    ?paper prism:keyword "hydrogen"^^xsd:string .
    ?paper fabio:hasDiscipline ?field .
    ?paper dcterms:title ?paperTitle .
    ?paper prism:publicationDate ?paperPubDate .
  }
}
LIMIT 100
```

In general, it seems like it's not working when I want to query by a specific string.

Do you have any hints?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The makg.org server is Virtuoso which uses RDF 1.0 for data so "hydrogen"^^xsd:string != "hydrogen".

Apache Jena Fuseki uses RDF 1.1 where "hydrogen"^^xsd:string is the same as "hydrogen" .

The problem is that the query sent is sending "hydrogen" because it is reconstructing the query service-part into a string using RDF 1.1 abbreviations.

The way round this using Fuseki is to use a filter.

```
?paper prism:keyword ?X . FILTER(str(?X) = "hydrogen")
```

Strictly `str()` isn't needed (SPARQL defines "=" as string-value, not same-term) but makg.org does need it.

---

In addition, the LIMIT needs to go to makg.org server by putting it inside the SERVICE:

```
PREFIX ...

SELECT ?paperTitle ?paperPubDate WHERE {
  SERVICE <https://makg.org/sparql> {
    SELECT * {
      ?paper rdf:type magc:Paper .
      ?paper prism:keyword "hydrogen"^^xsd:string .
      ?paper fabio:hasDiscipline ?field .
      ?paper dcterms:title ?paperTitle .
      ?paper prism:publicationDate ?paperPubDate .
    } LIMIT 100
  }
}
```